# Foreach on Array taking too loong

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am writing a script which should return me two values in an array from my database in combination with Wordpress and WooCommmerce.

However the script is taking forever to load so I either get a 524 from cloudflare or it finishes and displays nothing. I already set Max execution time to 1 hour.

Is there maybe anything that can be optimized with my code to achieve the same thing?

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
include 'wp-load.php';

function user_balance($user_id){

    $args = array(
    'customer' => $user_id,
    );

$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
$count           = 0;
 foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) :
    $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
    $invs  = $order->get_meta( 'type', true, 'view' );
    if ( $order->status == "completed" ):
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ) {
            $count += $item_data->get_quantity();
        }
    endif;
 endforeach;
return $count;
}

if(current_user_can('administrator')){
$args = array(
'blog_id'      => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
'role'         => '',
'role__in'     => array(),
'role__not_in' => array(),
'meta_key'     => '',
'meta_value'   => '',
'meta_compare' => '',
'meta_query'   => array(),
'date_query'   => array(),        
'include'      => array(),
'exclude'      => array(),
'orderby'      => 'login',
'order'        => 'ASC',
'offset'       => '',
'search'       => '',
'number'       => '',
'count_total'  => false,
'fields'       => 'ID',
'who'          => '',
); 

$userIDs = get_users($args);



foreach($userIDs as $key=>$userID){

$userID = array(
 'uid' => $userID,
 'balance' => user_balance($userID[$key])
);

}  

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($userIDs); echo '</pre>';


 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Code looks ok, probably a server issue (very slow, very little ram). Is it a shared hosting? Move on a vps with a minimum 1go ram for wordpress (yeah i know, it's shit)

Comment: Well I am having a Root Server with Linux and 4 x 3,5 GHz
32 GB ECC RAM DDR4. Is there anything that I could do to keep it buffering or having it display the array in realtime? btw The array contains about 10000 entries.

Comment: Okay,nice beast! Try to examine carefully what's going on system side. Where is the funnel. Check `top`, `iostat`, internet connectivity. Try a little `sleep(1)` in your loop, just before ` endforeach;` These are just suggestions, good luck!

Comment: is there a way I can execute the script with ssh? I mean I only need the values it returns, nothing more. I dont need to build a website or whatever from it. Could I also store everything in a file? Would that solve the problem?

Comment: Yep to store the output in a file, instead of echo, do `file_put_contents("output.txt",$userIDs,FILE_APPEND)` or transform your script as bash script, then `./myscript.php > output.txt` you need to dig a bit around. You can use ssh in your script too, but there is no point (the remote will works hard, not your station)